# Bellman-ford algorithm with capacity constraint - Python

Tags: python

I am implementing a Bellman-ford shortest path algorithm. Based on the source and destination node, it outputs the shortest distance, and the path through a network.

Now, I need to add a capacity component to the algorithm. So if the demand is 2 but the capacity is 1, that path is no longer usable.

My initial idea was to add a dictionary for the capacity and a variable for the demand. Then if the demand exceeded the capacity of a node, the lenght of the path would be arbritrarily large. I was thinking something like:

```
           if capacity[neighbour] < demand:
                distance[neighbour], predecessor[neighbour] = 999
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'
```

Is there a workaround for this issue, or could I potentially add the demand-constraint in a smarter way?

Full code:

```
source = 'e'
destination = 'd'
demand = 2

def bellman_ford(graph, source, capacity):
# Step 1: Prepare the distance and predecessor for each node
distance, predecessor = dict(), dict()

for node in capacity:
    for node in graph:
        distance[node], predecessor[node] = float('inf'), None
        distance[source] = 0

# Step 2: Relax the edges
for _ in range(len(graph) - 1):
    for node in graph:
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            # If the distance between the node and the neighbour is lower than the current, store it
            if distance[neighbour] > distance[node] + graph[node][neighbour]:
                distance[neighbour], predecessor[neighbour] = distance[node] + graph[node][neighbour], node
            if capacity[node] < demand:
                distance[neighbour], predecessor[neighbour] = 100


# Step 3: Check for negative weight cycles
for node in graph:
    for neighbour in graph[node]:
        assert distance[neighbour] <= distance[node] + graph[node][neighbour], "Negative weight cycle."

return distance, predecessor

#Initial graph

graph = {
    'a': {'b': 1, 'd':  1},
    'b': {'c':  1, 'd':  2},
    'c': {},
    'd': {'b':  1, 'c':  8, 'e': 1},
    'e': {'a': 2, 'd': 7}
}


capacity = {
    'a': {'b': 4, 'd':  1},
    'b': {'c':  5, 'd':  4},
    'c': {},
    'd': {'b':  1, 'c':  3, 'e': 3},
    'e': {'a': 5, 'd': 3}
}


distance, predecessor = bellman_ford(graph, source, capacity)

print("The cost of shipping from from", source, "to", destination, "is", distance[destination])

for i in graph:
    print("node",i,"is reached through node", predecessor[i])
```

Comment: There is no `if capacity[neighbour] < demand:` in full code

Comment: + it may be `if capacity[node][neighbour] < demand`

Comment: Ill update the original question with the non-functioning part of the code
I get the same error with [node][neighbour]

Comment: You cannot have the same error with capacity[node][neighbour], but you may have a KeyError

Comment: It still gives me the dict vs. int error

Comment: Because you've written `capacity[node]` instead of `capacity[node][neighbour]`